# Rolling sum of one variable in data.frame in number of steps defined by another variable

Tags: r, dplyr, rolling-computation

I'm trying to sum up the values in a data.frame in a cumulative way.

I have this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = rep(1:2, each = 5),
  b = 1:10,
  step_window = c(2,3,1,2,4, 1,2,3,2,1)
)
```

I'm trying to sum up the values of `b`, within the groups `a`. The trick is, I want the sum of `b` values that corresponds to the number of rows following the current row given by `step_window`.

This is the output I'm looking for:

```
data.frame(
    a = rep(1:2, each = 5),
    step_window = c(2,3,1,2,4, 
                    1,2,3,2,1),
    b = 1:10,
    sum_b_step_window = c(3, 9, 3, 9, 5,
                          6, 15, 27, 19, 10)
  )
```

I tried to do this using the `RcppRoll` but I get an error `Expecting a single value`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(a) %>% 
  mutate(sum_b_step_window = RcppRoll::roll_sum(x = b, n = step_window))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if having variable window size is possible in any of the rolling function. Here is one way to do this using `map2_dbl` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(a) %>% 
  mutate(sum_b_step_window = purrr::map2_dbl(row_number(), step_window, 
                             ~sum(b[.x:(.x + .y - 1)], na.rm = TRUE)))

#      a     b step_window sum_b_step_window
#   <int> <int>       <dbl>             <dbl>
# 1     1     1           2                 3
# 2     1     2           3                 9
# 3     1     3           1                 3
# 4     1     4           2                 9
# 5     1     5           4                 5
# 6     2     6           1                 6
# 7     2     7           2                15
# 8     2     8           3                27
# 9     2     9           2                19
#10     2    10           1                10
```

Answer (score 2):

**1) rollapply**

`rollapply` in zoo supports vector widths.  `partial=TRUE` says that if the width goes past the end then use just the values within the data.  (Another possibility would be to use `fill=NA` instead in which case it would fill with NA's if there were not enough data left) .  `align="left"` specifies that the current value at each step is the left end of the range to sum.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  mutate(sum = rollapply(b, step_window, sum, partial = TRUE, align = "left")) %>%
  ungroup
```

**2) SQL**

This can also be done in SQL by left joining df to itself on the indicated condition and then for each row summing over all rows for which the condition matches.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select A.*, sum(B.b) as sum
  from df A 
  left join df B on B.rowid between A.rowid and A.rowid + A.step_window - 1
    and A.a = B.a
  group by A.rowid")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with the package `slider`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(slider)

df %>%
    group_by(a) %>% 
    mutate(sum_b_step_window = hop_vec(b, row_number(), step_window+row_number()-1, sum)) %>% 
    ungroup()
```

It is flexible on different window sizes.

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
       a     b step_window sum_b_step_window
   <int> <int>       <dbl>             <int>
 1     1     1           2                 3
 2     1     2           3                 9
 3     1     3           1                 3
 4     1     4           2                 9
 5     1     5           4                 5
 6     2     6           1                 6
 7     2     7           2                15
 8     2     8           3                27
 9     2     9           2                19
10     2    10           1                10
```

---

`slider` is a couple-of-months-old `tidyverse` package specific for sliding window functions. Have a look here for more info: [page](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/02/slider-0-1-0/), [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/slider/vignettes/slider.html)

`hop` is the engine of `slider`. With this solution we are triggering different `.start` and `.stop` to sum the values of `b` according to the `a` groups.

With `_vec` you're asking `hop` to return a vector: a double in this case.

`row_number()` is a `dplyr` function that allows you to return the row number of each group, thus allowing you to slide along the rows.

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` solution using cumulative sums

```
setDT(df)
df[, sum_b_step_window := {
  cs <- c(0,cumsum(b))
  cs[pmin(.N+1, 1:.N+step_window)]-cs[pmax(1, (1:.N))]
},by = a]
```